# Docker sync volumes

Tags: typescript, docker, docker-compose, next.js, dockerfile

So... I trying start learning Docker. But I can't sync the host and the container using volumes on change and save code (using the npm run dev). All the time I have to restart the `docker-compose up --build` to the "sync" kick in, but after this any change don't update the folder or code.   My exemple code:

install Next.js typescript as base.

```
npx create-next-app@latest --ts
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  node-myname:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerFile.dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: "npm run dev"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/home/node/app/
```

DockerFile:

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY . .

RUN npm install
```

The recomended is using volumes insted bind...

I can't find a workaround.

Comment: create too a ".dockerignore"   **/node_modules

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need Docker for this setup.  If you install Node on your host, I'd expect you to be able to `npm run dev` normally, without trying to figure out Docker and the details of bind mounts.

Comment: @DavidMaze hum... i can install next.js inside container and copy it's contains with "docker exec -it <containercode> bash"   to the host past. But, it's more complicad and not simple exemple. I need to undestend docker to use on cloud services. They say this is the newest tecnolog (containers) and i need to know it.

Comment: If you're deploying this in a cloud environment, you won't have access to your local files.  Correspondingly, you should delete the `volumes:` block in the Compose file.  This will separate the Docker environment from your local setup, and you'll need to rebuild the image whenever you make a change.  You can still use plain Node for normal development and Docker to deploy; don't feel compelled to use Docker in development because it's part of your deployment process, or to use it just because it's "the new thing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need to use same path?!

```
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/app/
```

UPD: Checkout: https://github.com/theanurin/stackoverflow.68511005 and see INITLOG.md with steps "how to setup the project"

Comment: I changed the path and same result... no sync

Comment: and erros responses: ready - 

 project-name | warn  - Attempted to load @next/swc-linux-x64-gnu, but it was not installed
 project-name | warn  - Attempted to load @next/swc-linux-x64-gnux32, but it was not installed      
projet-name  | warn  - Attempted to load @next/swc-linux-x64-musl, but it was not installed

Comment: and if a try this on my WSL on windows result in "/tmp/dev-76d4fbb7.sh: 1: /tmp/dev-76d4fbb7.sh: next: not found".

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/theanurin/stackoverflow.73518453/blob/master/INITLOG.md
I'm made this work...
I does not have Windows to test, this was tested on MacOS. May be you have some issues with your Docker. Try reproduce issues on another host...

Comment: i don't know why... but after total reinstall (using Revo uninstaller)... the sync is working! But, after that the hot reaload using dev don't work on Docker. I solve this using another StackOverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126848/why-nextjs-using-docker-container-did-not-reload-after-changed-code-for-dev-envi         Install on the next.config.js and all finaly work as intended. I don't know why... but if i try the same path as before i get a error... but all work now!

Answer (score 1):

After total reinstall Docker Windows (using Revo uninstaller)... the sync is working (i can create a file .txt and this is show on docker exec)! But, after that the hot reaload using `dev` don't work on Docker. I solve this using another StackOverflow post: [Solution Docker Hot Reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126848/why-nextjs-using-docker-container-did-not-reload-after-changed-code-for-dev-envi) Install on the next.config.js.

Another thing... if i copy all the stuff from Nextjs host to the Docker container the Sync go way again... so... I can only copy `COPY package.json ./` from host.

next.config.js:

```
 /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
    const nextConfig = {
      reactStrictMode: true,
      swcMinify: true,
      // add to hot reaload work... windows
      webpackDevMiddleware: config => {
        config.watchOptions = {
          poll: 800,
          aggregateTimeout: 300,
        }
        return config
      },
    }
    
    module.exports = nextConfig
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  node-myname:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerFile.dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: "npm run dev"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/app
```

and all finaly work as intended. I don't know why... but if i try the same path as before i get a error... but all work now!

[Git Hub Final Code](https://github.com/novoytalo/Next.js-Docker-sync-volumes-on-Windows-)